# Boost::factory with boost::pool_allocator usage

Tags: c++, memory, boost, factory, allocator

I'm trying to learn about boost::factory and specifically using it with custom allocators

```
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/functional/factory.hpp>
#include <boost/pool/pool_alloc.hpp>
class Foo{
public:
    Foo() {};
    Foo(const std::string param) : m_param(param)
    const std::string param() const { return m_param; }
private:
    const std::string m_param;

};

int main(int argc,char** argv)  {
    // This doesn't work
    boost::factory<Foo*,boost::pool_allocator<Foo*>> g;
    // But this does
    boost::factor<boost::shared_ptr<Foo>,boost::pool_allocator<Foo>> h;

    auto x = h("http://www.bar.com");
    // Test to call a method
    x->param();

    // Release memory - do I need to do that for shared_ptr?
boost::singleton_pool<boost::pool_allocator_tag,sizeof(Download)>::release_memory();
    return 0;
}
```

My questions
1. Why does the first version not work?
2. Why do I need to release the memory for allocator if shared_ptr is doing it anyway? Or is the allocator just for construction, and destruction is handled by shared_ptr? Just trying to understand the semantics and 'best practice'